# Options for arranging balls in a line

Tags: combinatorics

We have unlimited balls from $8$ colors. Balls from the same color are identical. How many options are there to arrange them in a line of $10$, so that line will include exactly $4$ different color?

Comment: Pl. edit in what you have tried so far and what is causing a difficulty for you

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please [edit] these facts into your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Answer (score 0):

Let the *$10$* balls (numbered from $1-10$ according to their position) be placed in a row

The $4$ colours (out of $8$) for these balls can be selected in **$C(8,4)$** $(=70)$ ways

Now, in order to decide the colour of each numbered ball, we have to **distribute $10$ balls among the $4$ selected colours**, such that *no colour gets 0 balls*

This can be done in these many ways $4¹⁰ - C(4,1)×3¹⁰ + C(4,2)×2¹⁰ - C(4,3)×1¹⁰ = 818,520$

(for *each selection of $4$ colours*) using **Principle of Inclusion & Exclusion**

So, the final answer would be $70 × 818,520 = 57,296,400$

Comment: Hi! Please encourage new users to improve their questions before answering them. This helps stem the tide of questions that merely ask homework-style questions without any context.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know about this policy. Will keep in mind next time

Comment: No problem! Some people may even down-vote answers to PSQs (problem-statement questions). Not too many, but it does happen. Just saying don't be discouraged if it does.